# GStreamer GstVideoTestSrcPattern enum - where is it?

Tags: c, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying to set the "pattern" for my `videotestsrc`:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

GstElement *pipeline, *source, *sink;
...
source = gst_element_factory_make("videotestsrc", "source");
g_object_set(source, "pattern", GST_VIDEO_TEST_SRC_BALL, NULL);
```

Compiling, I get:

```
error: ‘GST_VIDEO_TEST_SRC_BALL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

What header do I need to include to have a declaration for the `GstVideoTestSrcPattern` enum? I've grepped around a bit and can't find it.

Comment: Please, accept the answer if it was helpful and right.

Comment: A note to make this question easier to find: this applies to all named constants for plugins. For example: [`halignment` property of `GstBaseTextOverlay`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/pango/GstBaseTextOverlay.html?gi-language=c#GstBaseTextOverlay:halignment) → [`Base-text-overlay-halign` named constant](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/pango/GstBaseTextOverlay.html?gi-language=c#GstBaseTextOverlayHAlign) → `GstBaseTextOverlayHAlign` enum defined [here](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-base/blob/master/ext/pango/gstbasetextoverlay.h) is inaccessible.

Comment: Related: how this is handled in the GStreamer Rust bindings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62138472/how-to-set-the-type-for-a-non-standard-gstreamer-property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GstVideoTestSrcPattern` enum is defined in gst-plugins-base, in the *gst/videotestsrc/gstvideotestsrc.h* header. This is a header that is not exposed in any way (since it would mean that the GstVideoTestSrc struct would become part of the public API/ABI). As such, you can't use the actual enum symbol.

To solve this, you can use the corresponding integer value (in this case, 18). If you're actually setting the property with something like `gst-launch-1.0` or its C equivalent `gst_parse_launch()`, you can actually use `videotestsrc pattern=ball`, which will also work.

*(Note: you could even implement the aforementioned kind of string deserialization yourself with the help of `gst_value_deserialize()`, but it would still require you to put in a string that is not checked at compile-time)*

Finally, if you're unsure what the various values of the enum are, you can use `gst-inspect-1.0 videotestsrc` as a cheat sheet.