# How to set the type for a non-standard gstreamer property?

Tags: rust, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm attempting to set the `pattern` property for the `videotestsrc`. Following the normal logic, I have tried setting the variable as an `i32` and a string. Both fail with an error that asks for a specific type.

Looking in the gstreamer API, I could not see a way to set the property.

How do you force the type of a variable to match the expected?

```
let pattern = "snow";
src.set_property("pattern", &pattern)
    .expect("setting pattern error");
```

error message

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'setting pattern error: BoolError { message: "property \'pattern\' of type \'GstVideoTestSrc\' can\'t be set from the given type (expected: \'GstVideoTestSrcPattern\', got: \'gchararray\')",
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set it by string via [`src.set_property_from_str("snow")`](https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/gstreamer/trait.GObjectExtManualGst.html#tymethod.set_property_from_str).

Alternatively you can use the [`glib::EnumClass`](https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/glib/struct.EnumClass.html) API to get all the possible values for the type. You can get the type via [`src.find_property("pattern")`](https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/glib/object/trait.ObjectExt.html#tymethod.find_property) and then [`get_value_type()`](https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/glib/struct.ParamSpec.html#method.get_value_type) on it.

Comment: thx Sebastian. Can you tell me if there is some logic to map the error `BoolError` to knowing it is set from  `set_property_from_string`. rather than from the `int` equivalent (1)?

Comment: The error tells you that the expected type of the property is a `GstVideoTestSrcPattern` and not a `gchararray` (i.e. a string), but you provided the latter. When using `set_property_from_str()` you can also provide the integer value of it, if you want. Internally it is using the `EnumClass` API (which I mentioned above) to convert from string or integer value to the actual enum value.