# GStreamer PyGObject Flag and Enum usage

Tags: gstreamer, pygobject

I am using PyGObject to run Gstreamer pipelines from python.
I need to set properties of some of my GStreamerElements, for example, the `profiles` property of the `rtspclientsink` element.

I am using the `<element>.set_property(name, val)` PyGObject equivalent of the GObject `set_property` function.

However, in this particular case, `val` is a flag, `GstRTSPProfile`. I was wondering how I might import and instantiate this flag as a python type such that I can set this property without having to just use an integer.

This is how I am importing Gstreamer:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstBase', '1.0')

from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, GstBase
```

Importing `GstRTSPProfile` from `gi.repository` does not work. I'm not able to access `GstRTSPProfile` from `Gst` or `GstBase` either.

Answer (score 0):

To set a property by string value as you would with `gst-launch-1.0`, you can use `Gst.util_set_object_arg` as outlined in this documentation: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gst-1.0/functions.html#Gst.util_set_object_arg. `Gst.util_set_object_arg` will silently do nothing on failure (property doesn't exist, string is not a valid value) though which you may want to check for.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `gobject.GEnum` by asking the element that uses it (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62139101/104446). Here's an example using the `queue` element and `leaky` property.

```
enum_class = Gst.ElementFactory.make("queue").find_property("leaky").enum_class
```

I couldn't figure out how to use this directly in a useful way - the class needs to be instantiated with the integer value. e.g.

```
>>> enum_class(1)
<enum Leaky on upstream (new buffers) of type __main__.GstQueueLeaky>
```

But you can create a Python enum from it:

```
>>> GstQueueLeaky = IntEnum(
...     enum_class.__name__,
...     {v.value_nick.upper(): k for k, v in enum_class.__enum_values__.items()}
... )

>>> GstQueueLeaky.DOWNSTREAM
<GstQueueLeaky.DOWNSTREAM: 2>

>>> GstQueueLeaky.__members__
mappingproxy({
    'NO': <GstQueueLeaky.NO: 0>, 
    'UPSTREAM': <GstQueueLeaky.UPSTREAM: 1>, 
    'DOWNSTREAM': <GstQueueLeaky.DOWNSTREAM: 2>
})
```